# Rails Angular Webpacker can't import CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, webpacker

When I importing CSS to Angular component like this:

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'hello-angular',
   styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],   
   template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
 })
```

rails returns error

> GET http://localhost:3000/app.component.css 406 (Not Acceptable)

but when I add styles to component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-angular',
  styles: [`
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
  `],
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
```

everything works great.

Is it possible to import external component CSS with rails webpacker?

Comment: The error is showing you the problem:

path: `http://localhost:3000/app.component.css` is not in the folder structure after compiling. 

Where have you placed your CSS file? Is the component and the css file in the same folder?

Comment: I have the same issue. It looks like webpacker does not the support (via config) the default `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` from angular.